# How to use simpleHTMLdom parser with url that contains pagination?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simpleHTMLDom parser, it works very well with url like : `http://someWebSite.com/page/1` suppose that i want to parse from page 1 to page 20 (for website that contain pagination).

i've tried (naively) this :

```
for($page = 1; $page <= 20; $page++){
  $getHTML = file_get_html('http://website.com/page/'.$page);
 }
```

It doesn't work (it get the last page and it parses it)

Any help please ??

Comment: Maybe because you are overwriting all the previous content all the time... Try changeing `=` to `.=`

Comment: It just take the last url (http://website.com/page/20) and it parse the content it doesn't parse from page 1 to 20

Comment: You can't. `file_get_html` return an object, you can't concatenate objects. You have to load pages separately then importing nodes. I don't know if Simple HTML Dom can do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($page = 1; $page <= 20; $page++){
    $getHTML = file_get_html('http://website.com/page/'.$page);

    // <-- Do your stuff here
}
```

or

```
$getHTML = array();
for($page = 1; $page <= 20; $page++){
    $getHTML[] = file_get_html('http://website.com/page/'.$page);
}
foreach($getHTML as $html){
    // Do stuff with $html
}
```

You need to to something with the HTML befor you get the next one or store it and then to somethin with it.